# WPF - How to wait for all views to be loaded

Tags: mvvm, loaded

I have several views in MVVM design.
I need to do some logic after ALL views (and ViewModels) are loaded.
I can register to Loaded event for each view, but I need to know when ALL the views/ViewModels are loaded.

Is WPF support that ?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box I don't know of any construct that WPF provides.  However, depending on your implementation of loading views, it would not be too difficult to provide a solution.  For example, the loading method of each view could signal an external managing object.  Once it received the required number of signals, then you can react however you need to.